# Why is this Date JS function always a day behind?

Tags: javascript, date, iso

Can someone please help me understand why this set of functions always calculates the date a day behind?

```
const parseISOString = (isoStr) => {
  return new Date(Date.parse(isoStr))
}

const formatDt = () => {
  const dtInISOFmt = "2019-12-01T05:00:00.000+00:00"
  const dateStrParts = parseISOString(dtInISOFmt).toDateString().split(" ")
  const month = dateStrParts[1]
  const day = dateStrParts[2]
  const year = dateStrParts[3]
  return [day, month, year].join(" ")
}

console.log(`formatDt(): ${formatDt()}`)
```

Here's a quick plunkr with the same: https://plnkr.co/edit/X3EkEZM6uNDPA36w

Quick background: Was trying to do some basic date formatting/parsing without importing any major date formatting JS libraries (e.g. moment) into my application, to reduce it's size / footprint.

Any and all help much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `toDateString` uses your own timezone... Not UTC. Use `toUTCString` instead.

Comment: Thanks @trincot! That did the trick.

Comment: The use of *Date.parse* in `new Date(Date.parse(isoStr))` is entirely redundant, the result will be identical to `new Date(isoStr)`.

Comment: Also see [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)